# LINQ into SortedList

Tags: c#, linq, sortedlist, sorteddictionary

I'm a complete LINQ newbie, so I don't know if my LINQ is incorrect for what I need to do or if my expectations of performance are too high.

I've got a SortedList of objects, keyed by int; SortedList as opposed to SortedDictionary because I'll be populating the collection with pre-sorted data.  My task is to find either the exact key or, if there is no exact key, the one with the next higher value.  If the search is too high for the list (e.g. highest key is 100, but search for 105), return null.

```
// The structure of this class is unimportant.  Just using
// it as an illustration.
public class CX
{
    public int KEY;
    public DateTime DT;
}

static CX getItem(int i, SortedList<int, CX> list)
{
    var items =
    (from kv in list
     where kv.Key >= i
     select kv.Key);

    if (items.Any())
    {
        return list[items.Min()];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Given a list of 50,000 records, calling getItem 500 times takes about a second and a half.  Calling it 50,000 times takes over 2 minutes.  This performance seems very poor.  Is my LINQ bad?  Am I expecting too much?  Should I be rolling my own binary search function?

Comment: The standard `List` class actually has a `BinarySearch` method built in, which you can use; see my answer below.

Comment: tzaman was right to suggest using a built-in `BinarySearch` method; it's just that using `List<T>.BinarySearch` isn't the way to go because it requires having your keys in a `List<T>`. I've posted an answer that includes code for an extension method on any `IList<T>` (this includes the `SortedList<TKey, TValue>.Keys` property) taken straight from Microsoft's binary search implementation. You may find it useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a binary search on your own can be tough.

Fortunately, Microsoft already wrote a pretty robust one: `Array.BinarySearch<T>`. [This is, in fact, the method that `SortedList<TKey, TValue>.IndexOfKey` uses internally](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/whats-annoying-about-sortedlisttkey-tvalue-indexofkey-a-k-a-whats-sweet-about-reflector/). Only problem is, it takes a `T[]` argument, instead of any `IList<T>` (like `SortedList<TKey, TValue>.Keys`).

You know what, though? There's this great tool called [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) that lets you look at .NET source code...

Check it out: a generic `BinarySearch` extension method on `IList<T>`, taken straight from the reflected code of Microsoft's `Array.BinarySearch<T>` implementation.

```
public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> list, int index, int length, T value, IComparer<T> comparer) {
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    else if (index < 0 || length < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException((index < 0) ? "index" : "length");
    else if (list.Count - index < length)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    int lower = index;
    int upper = (index + length) - 1;

    while (lower <= upper) {
        int adjustedIndex = lower + ((upper - lower) >> 1);
        int comparison = comparer.Compare(list[adjustedIndex], value);
        if (comparison == 0)
            return adjustedIndex;
        else if (comparison < 0)
            lower = adjustedIndex + 1;
        else
            upper = adjustedIndex - 1;
    }

    return ~lower;
}

public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> list, T value, IComparer<T> comparer) {
    return list.BinarySearch(0, list.Count, value, comparer);
}

public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> list, T value) where T : IComparable<T> {
    return list.BinarySearch(value, Comparer<T>.Default);
}
```

This will let you call `list.Keys.BinarySearch` and get the negative bitwise complement of the index you want in case the desired key isn't found (the below is taken basically straight from tzaman's answer):

```
int index = list.Keys.BinarySearch(i);
if (index < 0)
    index = ~index;
var item = index < list.Count ? list[list.Keys[index]] : null;
return item;
```

Comment: Nice! This extension combined with my answer would be the definitive way to solve this, I think.

Comment: This is the one.  Thank you and thanks to others who answered as well.

Answer (score 7):

First, your query is being evaluated twice (once for `Any`, and once for `Min`). Second, `Min` requires that it iterate over the entire list, even though the fact that it's sorted means that the first item will be the minimum. You should be able to change this:

```
if (items.Any())
{
    return list[items.Min()];
}
```

To this:

```
var default = 
    (from kv in list
     where kv.Key >= i
     select (int?)kv.Key).FirstOrDefault();

if(default != null) return list[default.Value];

return null;
```

**UPDATE**

Because you're selecting a value type, `FirstOrDefault` doesn't return a nullable object. I have altered your query to cast the selected value to an `int?` instead, allowing the resulting value to be checked for `null`. I would advocate this over using `ContainsKey`, as that would return `true` if your list contained a value for `0`. For example, say you have the following values

0 2 4 6 8

If you were to pass in anything less than or equal to 8, then you would get the correct value. However, if you were to pass in 9, you would get 0 (`default(int)`), which *is* in the list but *isn't* a valid result.

Comment: Wow, yeah.  That changed 2 minutes to 1/2 a second.

Comment: Since FirstOrDefault is going to be returning the int key here, I needed to change default.Value to just default.  A couple things, though: What is the "Default" here?  I can't seem to find the meaning of that in MSDN.  And since I don't know that, I need to check list.ContainsKey(default) before I return list[default];  Fortunately, that doesn't add any significant time to the execution.

Comment: Would the default just be the default for int, 0?

Comment: n/m on the default question.  I see this means 0 for value types.

Comment: @Chris: for more information on default, look up the default() keyword in c#.

Comment: Are you sure `KeyValuePair` can be null? `KeyValuePair` is a value type as well.

Comment: @Dan: It appears that I should do this sort of thing while in Visual Studio. You're absolutely right, `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is, indeed, a value type, meaning that it can't be null. The OP's solution. I'll update as appropriate.

Comment: More concise version: `return list.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key >= i).Value;` Using the predicate version of `FirstOrDefault` avoids the need for the `int?` cast, null-check, and index into the list later. :)

Comment: @tzaman: D'oh, I'm having quite the off day today. I have no clue why I didn't think of using the query to obtain the value rather than the key. In retrospect that's a bit silly. Good solution; should be an answer instead of a comment!

Comment: @Adam: Well, it's still your answer, I just cleaned it up a bit! :) Feel free to edit it into yours.

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ on a `SortedList` will not give you the benefit of the sort.

For optimal performance, you should write your own binary search.

Comment: I had hoped not, but this is what I feared.  Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason that LINQ can't be used on the list in a way that respects the sorting. You just shouldn't expect functions like `Min` to be aware of the optimizations that can be made (ie, the fact that items are guaranteed to be in order in the list, so `Min` is just the first and `Max` is just the last).

Comment: @Adam Robinson: It still seems like SLaks is right, though; won't a `Where` followed by a `FirstOrDefault` essentially result in a linear search for the first matching value? Yes, that's better than `Min` (which would have to enumerate); but it's still not as fast as it *could* be. I don't think the LINQ extensions are specially aware of always-sorted collections such as `SortedList.Keys`. Am I wrong about that? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SLaks: Curious to know: why did you strike out the line about using binary search? It seems to me this was an accurate statement; what am I missing?

Comment: @Dan: No, they aren't aware of the internals of the data store (all they know is that it implements `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`), but that doesn't mean that you can't code a LINQ query (that's more than just a simple value search) that takes advantage of the sorted nature of the list. You're right in that it is performing a linear search, but that's what the list would do internally (this is a `SortedList`, not a `SortedDictionary`, which would use a hash table). Furthermore, because the OP wants to find *the value or the next highest if it isn't present*, a linear search is required.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I must be missing something. How is a linear search required? If the OP wrote a binary search to find the index of the matching or next highest key, he could get the value with `list[Keys[indexOfMatchingOrNextHighestKey]]`.

Comment: While a binary search is the right answer, rolling your own isn't necessary; see my answer.

Comment: @Dan: A binary search could be used to optimize finding the key and determining its existence. You would still need to move to the next element if the requested key could not be found, but given the OP's apparent results it seems like a LINQ-based linear search is *easier*, if not necessarily the most efficient. My first statement was simply meant to indicate that you can tailor a LINQ query (to an extent) if you know that the data store is sorted. My second statement (stating that a linear search is *required*) was a misstatement; I merely meant that a binary search *alone* couldn't be used.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Also, a linear search is actually *not* what `SortedList` does internally; according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132336.aspx), the `IndexOfKey` method does run a binary search. Only problem is that it returns -1 if the key isn't found (instead of the bitwise complement of the next index, like `List<T>.BinarySearch does). The OP basically needs `IndexOfKey` but with the behavior of `List<T>.BinarySearch`.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Fair enough. I definitely agree that a LINQ-based linear search is substantially easier to do.

Comment: @Dan: I stand corrected! `SortedList` isn't a structure that I find much opportunity to use, so it's good to get an opportunity to be schooled a bit ;)

Answer (score 2):

OK, just to give this a little more visibility - here's a more concise version of Adam Robinson's answer:

```
return list.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key >= i).Value;
```

The `FirstOrDefault` function has an overload that accepts a predicate, which selects the first element satisfying a condition - you can use that to directly get the element you want, or `null` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `BinarySearch` that's built into the `List` class?

```
var keys = list.Keys.ToList();
int index = keys.BinarySearch(i);
if (index < 0)
    index = ~index;
var item = index < keys.Count ? list[keys[index]] : null;
return item;
```

If the search target isn't in the list, `BinarySearch` returns the bit-wise complement of the next-higher item; we can use that to directly get you what you want by re-complementing the result if it's negative. If it becomes equal to the `Count`, your search key was bigger than anything in the list.

<strike>This should be much faster than doing a LINQ `where`, since it's already sorted...</strike>
As comments have pointed out, the `ToList` call will force an evaluation of the whole list, so this is only beneficial if you do multiple searches without altering the underlying `SortedList`, and you keep the `keys` list around separately.

Comment: Whoa, this will definitely not be faster. `ToList` will populate an entirely new `List`. This makes it O(n) minimum, in addition to a whole added memory cost.

Comment: While this is an interesting idea, transforming a `SortedList` into a `List` in this fashion is going to evaluate every element of the underlying `SortedList` individually anyway.

Comment: Oh drat, of course. That brings up the question, why isn't there a `BinarySearch` method on the `SortedList` class itself? It'd seem like a no-brainer...

On the other hand, if you're doing more than one search in a row without altering the SortedList, you can keep the `Keys` list around separately, which would make this approach worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Using OrderedDictionary in PowerCollections you can get an enumerator that starts where they key you are looking for should be... if it's not there, you'll get the next closest node and can then navigate forwards/backwards from that in O(log N) time per nav call.

This has the advantage of you not having to write your own search or even manage your own searches on top of a SortedList.

Comment: Another third party solution: [`BDictionary<Key,Value>`](http://loyc.net/doc/code/classLoyc_1_1Collections_1_1BDictionary_3_01K_00_01V_01_4.html) in LoycCore.